# Why is matplotlib coloring my plot with so many colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting multiple objects, both consisting of multiple straight lines. To do so, I use a list of colors and assign one to each object. The desired result looks like this:
[image: two colors]
I am doing this with the command `plt.plot`, providing a start and end point, and a color.

While trying to get to this result, I made a mistake, and instead of names like `'pink'`, I provided values like `(0, 0.75, 0)`.
Which resulted in this:
[image: many colors]

Why does matplotlib behave this way? I would like to understand how it comes that each segment has its own color, seemingly chosen at random, when I have always provided the same incorrect input.

I was unable to find documentation of the behaviour when no correct input value is passed. If there is documentation, a quote of the relevant part would already constitute an answer if matplotlib actually just chooses at random every time.

The same behaviour happens when I pass `False` instead of a color.

---

**MCVE**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Line in black
plt.plot([-1,-1], [-1,1], 'k')
# Line in bad color
plt.plot([0,0],[-1,1], False)
# Line in same bad color
plt.plot([1,1],[-1,1], False)
# Line in other bad color
plt.plot([2,2],[-1,1], (0,0.75,0))
# Line in same other bad color
plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], (0,0.75,0))
plt.show()
```

[image: MCVE Result Image]

---

**Note:**
I am not looking for how to get my desired result by passing a constant color. I managed that. But on the way there, I encountered this behaviour, which I'd like to understand.
Based on the comments, it seems likely that there is some documented and well-known functionality in pyplot that simply uses a color cycle and takes the next color in it whenever no valid color is provided. I am not able to find documentation on that though, so I would like either some documentation quote, or the answer that this is undocumented behaviour, or something along those lines.

It is also worth pointing out that something in the middle of the image was also drawn when I was using invalid color parameters, but not when using correct values. Why?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing code, preferably a [mcve]

Comment: Sure, give me a moment. It's really just using the command `plt.plot(a,b, False)` multiple times

Comment: Each call to `plt.plot` will go to the next color in the cycle

Comment: @lucidbrot: You can define the color so that the lines are all plotted in same color even after using the for loop. You can use some if condition on the index so that you get two colors: green and blue

Comment: @DavidG added MCVE. Do you have some documentation link on the color cycle? I just basically implemented that for myself because I didn't find docu for it (just for each object instead of each line)

Comment: @lucidbrot: What exactly is the issue with the MCVE you provided? Which lines needs to be what color?

Comment: @Bazingaa it's less an issue than just me being curious. My question is "Why does matplotlib behave this way?". See the note I edited in at the end of my question, maybe that makes it clearer what I'm looking for. I would have expected the MCVE to color the lines with the same (invalid) color parameter in the same color - and it obviously does not do that, but I am unable to find documentation on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call signature of [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-plot) is completely crazy. This is because it has grown over time and is one of the most used functions, hence it's always kept backward compatible.

The documentation states the following ways to call this function.

```
plot([x], y, [fmt], data=None, **kwargs)
plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)
```

Arguments in square brackets are optional and the ellipses denote an arbitrary number of further arguments to be passed.

Going through the cases from above, and renaming the respective arguments:

#### 1.

```
plt.plot([-1,-1], [-1,1], 'k')
plt.plot(   x   ,    y  , fmt)
```

As expected `'k'` is the format to be used.

#### 2.

```
plt.plot([0,0],[-1,1], False)
plt.plot(  x  ,   y  ,   y2 )
```

Here, `False` is no valid format string. Hence it is interpreted as data for a new line. Since there is no other following argument that can be interpreted, it cannot be `x2`, hence it must be `y2`. `False` is equivalent to `0`. So you would get a single point at (0,0), which you don't see in the plot, because there is no marker specified. If you were to use

```
plt.plot([0,0],[-1,1], False, "o")
```

instead, you'd see the single point in orange.

[image]

#### 3.

Same as above. The only difference is that you get the line in a different color according to the color cycler in use (see below in this answer).

#### 4.

```
plt.plot([2,2],[-1,1], (0,0.75,0))
plt.plot(  x  ,   y  ,     y2    )
```

Again, the third argument is no valid format string. It is again interpreted as the y values of a further line. This time, in contrast to 2. and 3.,  `y2` contains several coordinates. Therefore a line along the points `(0,0), (1,0.75), (2,0)` is drawn.

[image]

---

In all but the first case, no color is specified. In that case according to the docs

> By default, each line is assigned a different style specified by a 'style cycle'. The fmt and line property parameters are only necessary if you want explicit deviations from these defaults. Alternatively, you can also change the style cycle using the 'axes.prop_cycle' rcParam.

Since the default property cycler only contains color, you will hence get the same linestyle everywhere, but in a different color.

You may print the default cycler

```
print(plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"])

# cycler('color', ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd', '#8c564b',
#                   '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf'])
```

Or you may set it

```
plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = plt.cycler("color", ["red", "#001eff", (0, 0.75, 0)])
```

An example is available on the matplotlib page: [Styling with cycler](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/color_cycler.html) and also [Colors in the default property cycle](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/color_cycle_default.html)

`cycler` also has its own documentation page, https://matplotlib.org/cycler/ as it may equally be used for other things outside of matplotlib.

Coming back to the start of the question; in order to get all lines in the same color, it is possible to set the color cycler to a single color

```
plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = plt.cycler("color", ["k"])
```

In this case, all lines in the axes will appear black.

Comment: The perfect theory addition to the other answer with the examples! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code it is hard to answer,
But can you try assign colour explicitly? What is more, you can not do `plt.plot(x,y,color)`, you need to write the name of params explicitly like this
`plt.plot(x,y,c = color)` or `plt.plot(x,y,color = color)`

You can try this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


blue = (0,0,0.75)
green = (0, 0.75, 0)
# Line in black
plt.plot([-1,-1], [-1,1], color = blue)
# Line in bad color
plt.plot([0,0],[-1,1] , color = blue)
# Line in same bad color
plt.plot([1,1],[-1,1], color = blue)
# Line in other bad color
plt.plot([2,2],[-1,1], color = green)
# Line in same other bad color
plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], color = green)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And the reason of you can use `plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], "green")` rather than `plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], green)` is from the [plot documentaion](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).

The default third parameter is fmt and its definition is, A format string consists of a part for color, marker and line: fmt = '[color][marker][line]'.
I think the `plot` function will work properly if it recognize the third parameter is the accepted string.

Instead of feeding '(0, 0.75, 0)' than `"green"`, the function will treat '(0, 0.75, 0)' as a line segment of `x = (0, 1, 2) y =(0, 0.75, 0)`, so that is why there is a additional line segment on your plot. And normally the plot will assign a default color to it.

Comment: Okay, wait... so `plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], color = green)` in your example sets the color to green. `plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], green)` sets the color to a random color. But `plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], `pink`)` makes the color pink. Why? Why doesn't it either always require the keyword or never?

Comment: @lucidbrot Did you use `plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], "pink")` rather than `plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], pink)`.  Because the `green` is not `"green"`, it is a value of (0,0.75,0). And `plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], "green")` will work as well. `"pink"` and `"green"` are accepted color in `matplotlib color`, so the function will automaticlly recognize these words. However, `green = (0,0.75,0)` need to be specifc addressed as the `color = green`

Comment: I understand the difference between a defined variable `green=(0,0.75,0)` and a string `"green"`. I do not understand why the keyword `color=` is needed with `plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], color=(0,0.75,0))` but not with `plt.plot([3,3],[-1,1], "green")`

Comment: @lucidbrot I updated my answer,  see if it makes sense.